# Retain sites/<site>/files path for cdn urls

Tags: path-aliases, cdn

I just updated the cdn module and seems the CDN urls formed for pdf (and other) attachments have been updated with the /public/ keyword.

Before:

```
https://cdn-domain/de/cdn/farfuture/<token_string>/sites/de/files/2022-05/file_name.pdf
```

where `de` is a multisite alias.

After the module upgrade the new path is rendered as

```
https://cdn-domain/de/cdn/ff/<token_string>/public/2022-05/file_name.pdf
```

Is there any way to retain the previous urls? i.e, when a new attachment is loaded, the url formed for the media file should be in the form of `.../sites/de/files/...` (which was before the module upgrade).

I think this is where all changed in the cdn module - https://www.drupal.org/node/3051642

Comment: That change occurred three years ago. Which versions did you upgrade from and to, precisely?

Comment: Updated from 8.x-3.2 to 8.x-3.5.

Comment: Just trying to find if there's a way (advanced mapping?) to use the old style path. If not - I think i'll need to proceed in fixing other parts (custom code) of the site that depended on `sites/<site>/files` format :(.